# Why does a generic type class representing a Tree have A and B types?

Tags: scala

In the book essential scala they have an example of representing a Tree using Generics/Types.

What I am confused is, say this is a Tree[Int].  So the left/right values are nodes, and the value is of type Int.

Why does the type parameter of fold have to be B and not A?  I'm confused why there are 2 types A and B and not just type A which is an Int if it is a Tree[Int].

```
sealed trait Tree[A] {
  def fold[B](node: (B, B) => B, leaf: A => B): B
}
final case class Node[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A] {
  def fold[B](node: (B, B) => B, leaf: A => B): B =
    node(left.fold(node, leaf), right.fold(node, leaf))
}
final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A] {
  def fold[B](node: (B, B) => B, leaf: A => B): B =
    leaf(value)
}
```

Comment: Why limit yourself to folding a **Tree** of **Ints** into an **Int**, when you could fold it into any other thing?  - Let's use a simpler data structure for an example, you have a **List** of **Ints** you can sum all its elements like `list.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)` or you could create a string that contains all its digits in order like `list.fold("")(_ + _.toString)` - so you can `fold` a **List** of **Int** into a **Int** or into a **String** or into whatever.

Comment: I'm confused why you need another type B.  If A is Int, you can just re-use the type parameter A no?

Comment: What? No, You need another type precisely because `A` is **Int**.  Look at the definition of foldLeft in **List** `def foldLeft[A, B](list: List[A])(z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B` so you can combine all the elements in the list into one single element of any type `B`, as long as you give me an initial value of that type `B` and you explain to me how to combine a value of that type `B` with a value of the current type `A` into a value of another type `B`. Now, in the case of summing all the elements of a **List** `B` is also **Int**, but in the case of concatenating them together `B` is **String**.

Comment: If the `Tree` is one type, `Int`, and your `fold()` target is a different type, `String`?, then you need 2 generics to describe the `Int`-to-`String` conversion, i.e. `A => B`.

Comment: so A and B might be the same, but because they could be different you have to be explicit

Answer (score 1):

Fold is an operation that reduces `F[A]` to a single value `B`.

You can of course reduce your tree of `Int` to a single `Int` (by adding the integers i.e.) in this case `A` and `B` would be the same.

But fold can do much more for you. You can also fold your tree to a String for example to print it's structure.

Fold is simply more general then you expected.